# What Types of relay i should use to control 0.5HP motor (150v to 250v)?

Tags: relay

i want to make a Curcuit to swith on or off 0.5 Hp motor(120v to 250v) with remote i need suggestion to choose relay i have 9v battery and i can also stepdown voltage as required so what type of relay i should use?

Comment: Please edit your [original question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/190086/can-i-use-6volt-relay-to-control-0-5hp-ac-motor) rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use a relay rated at 0.5HP or greater (as well as a 250VAC voltage rating and a current rating of at least several amperes- more likely 10A or more).

If it doesn't have a rating in HP, don't use it.

A PP3 9V battery will not power a relay suitable for 0.5HP+ for very long.